# How to make different kind of objects fall with same speed in Corona

Tags: coronasdk, physics

I have different images as display objects and I want them to fall with same speed in physics. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The density of the object's body must be all the same

```
physics.addBody(object,"dynamic",{density = 1)
```

Try this piece of code

```
local object1 = display.newRect(0,0,math.random(10,100),math.random(10,100))
object1.x = 100
object1.y = 0
physics.addBody(object1,"dynamic",{bounce = 1, friction = 0, density = 1})

local object2 = display.newRect(0,0,math.random(10,100),math.random(10,100))
object2.x = 200
object2.y = 0
physics.addBody(object2,"dynamic",{bounce = 1, friction = 0, density = 1})
```

Random sizes but same speed because of the density.

Comment: Try my updated answer, it will create 2 random sizes rects but falls in the same speed.

Comment: Okey but it's not happening with my images. May collision filter be troubling it? physics.addBody(item,"dynamic",{bounce = 1, friction = 0, density = 1, filter=collisionFilter})

Comment: No it should not, collision filter will only affect the collision events not the body itself. Maybe you have object.gravityScale?

Comment: Nope, I don't have that.

Comment: How do you make it fall? Like free fall? Do you have setLinearVelocity?

Comment: I just add them to Physics world like in my second comment, nothing else.